# How to open an external link by clicking on an image using SWIFT2.0?

Tags: swift2

I am using SwiftyJSON to download images from external website and show them in table view. I want to click on a particular image and have it open an external URL. How to achieve this?

Basically what I am doing by button press (as show below), I want to do by clicking image.

```
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! myCell

    let str = TableData[indexPath.row].thumbnail
    let imagePath = (str.substringToIndex(str.startIndex.advancedBy((str.characters.count)-11)))+".png" //Removing "-100x90.png" from each thumbnail path and appending extension .png later on to fetch original sized image

    cell.myImageView.kf_setImageWithURL(NSURL(string: imagePath)!)
    cell.myLabel.text = String(TableData[indexPath.row].date) + ":" + String(TableData[indexPath.row].title)
    print(TableData[indexPath.row].permalink)
    cell.myButton.tag = indexPath.row
    cell.myButton.addTarget(self, action: "openURL:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
    print(cell.myButton.tag) 
    return cell
}


func openURL(sender:UIButton){
print("Button Pressed")
UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string: TableData[sender.tag].permalink)!)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works with following code:

```
    let singleTap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action:"tapDetected:")
    singleTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
    cell.myImageView.userInteractionEnabled = true
    cell.myImageView.tag = indexPath.row
    cell.myImageView.addGestureRecognizer(singleTap)

func tapDetected(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string: TableData[(sender.view!.tag)].link)!)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a `UITapGestureRecognizer` to the image view in the cell:

```
let tapRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "openURL:")
cell.myImageView.addGestureRecognizer(tapRecognizer)
```